# Binding a jAlert popup content to html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to use jAlert to show a popup dialog with an input box. When clicking "OK" I want to grab the value from this input box to send to the server. I'm using jQuery to pull the content off a div which includes the input field. Problem is that when I use jQuery to try and get the contents of that input field, it doesn't work - it comes back as empty.

HTML as follows:

`<div id="test">
        <input type="text" id="def" />
    </div>`

JS as follows:

`$.jAlert({ 'content' : $("#test").html()});`

...and to try and access using jQuery...

`$("#def").val();`

I can get around it by force updating the field using a keyup listener, but it seems really clunky...

`<input type="text" id="def" onkeyup="$('#def').val($(this).val())" />`

After doing this I can access the content of the 'def' field. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: This one? https://github.com/VersatilityWerks/jAlert

Comment: Perhaps: `successAlert('Success',"Well done", function() { $.post("someserverProcess.php?def="+$('#def').val()); return "Sending result"}`

Comment: So `$("#test").html()` is empty? Try `$("#def").val()`

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, that plugin.

Comment: @mplungjan it's $("#def").val() that returns nothing after having typed into the input box.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? I've tried using JSFiddle. Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/9458e35y/

Comment: @mfirry - not exactly what I was after. Check this out... https://jsfiddle.net/pajohns/ko75zbf6/7/ - I want to refer to a form that is in the dom and be able to extract the info out of the text box. Doable?

Comment: I think I've made it work. Not super happy, but I think it does what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/ko75zbf6/8/

Comment: @mfirry thanks for this - this does work although not as elegantly as I'd hoped. It's pretty much the same as what I'd been doing only yours sets a variable externally to the method. I'm seeing if there are any other solutions from other modal popups.